# Convert jshort to unsigned short

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, opengl-es-2.0

I'm developing a Java program that uses some native calls.

Do you know an easy way to convert `jshort` to `unsigned short`? Or, can I use as equivalents types?

In native code I receive a `jshort` value and I need to use this value as `GLushort`.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Wow! -1 point and nodoby tells why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add 
`& 0xFF`
to it! It makes it unsigned :D

Answer (score 1):

Well, first see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface#Mapping_types). A `jshort` is actually a `short` (signed) so to convert it you have to handle negative values.

Why not use the `jchar` since it maps directly to a `unsigned short` - then you can cast directly.

```
jchar jC = ....;
GLushort s = (GLushort) jC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast to `GLushort` in your code.

The fact that `jshort` is signed does not matter unless the parameter can actually be used to hold negative values **and** you are doing arithmetic or integer comparisons in the Java side.